# EC2 with HTTPS using route53

Tags: express, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-route53

I recently deployed my Express server on an EC2 instance as the backend (BE) for my web application. I've successfully configured my front-end (FE) app with Route 53 using a newly purchased domain, along with S3 connected to CloudFront, and an SSL certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM).

Now, I'm struggling to set up HTTPS for my Express BE server using the same domain I just purchased through Route 53. Most online guides suggest using a load balancer for this, but I'm just learning and find it expensive. I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to achieve this, and what the advantages and disadvantages of each approach are?

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser());

// https : Self signed cert
// const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./key.pem", "utf8");
// const certificate = fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem", "utf8");
// const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
// const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(app);

httpsServer.listen(ports.https, () => {
  console.log("https server is running at port with HTTPS PROTOCOL", ports.https);
});
```

It works well with self-signed but i truly cant find a way to make it connected to my ACM from same domain i just used in route53 without a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates obtained through Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) have specific compatibility, primarily designed for services like Elastic Load Balancers, CloudFront, API Gateway, and other AWS services. However, they can't be directly installed on EC2 instances.

If you need to install an SSL certificate on your EC2 instance, ACM won't work for this purpose. You should procure an SSL certificate from a third-party source like Lets Encrypt or GoDaddy and then follow the installation instructions tailored to your web server.

While cost may be a concern, the recommendation is to place an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in front of your EC2 instance. This not only allows the ELB to manage the SSL certificate but also offers additional advantages, including:

1. AWS Shield protection, which enhances DDoS defense.
2. Improved scalability and flexibility for replacing or expanding EC2 instances in the future.
3. Offloading the encryption/decryption workload of HTTPS connections to the ELB, optimizing your EC2 instance's CPU for other tasks.

Comment: This is for private app , so i not expect a large traffic that requires ELB for now (at least not with this price). But your answer helps me a lot to understand , i will use certbot from lets encrypt . hope it will work. thanks .